# How to write a query in hibernate for count(*)

Tags: hibernate, hql

I want to execute the below query in *Hibernate*?

`select count(*) from login where emailid='something' and password='something'`

Comment: Um... how about `select count(*) from Login login where login.emailid='something' and login.password='something'`? Or are you asking how to execute a HQL query at all?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Suppose your `login` table is mapped by a `LoginClass` class, with `emailid` and `password` instance variables. Then you'll execute something like:

```
Query<?> query = session.createQuery(
                "select count(*) from LoginClass login where login.emailid=:email and login.password=:password");
        query.setParameter("email", "something");
        query.setParameter("password", "password");
        Long count = (Long)query.uniqueResult();
```

It should return in `count` the result you're looking for. You just have to adapt the name to your class and your parameter names.

Comment: On using it the same way, I am getting an error, table or view does not exist. The query with the tablename, is working fine in db. Any idea what the error is?

Comment: Works fine with Hibernate 5.3.1.

Comment: I had to use getSingleResult() instead uniqueResult(). The latter was not available

Comment: If anyone like me faced the error of _BigDecimal cannot cast it to Long_ when trying to use the solution above, use this:
`Long count = ((BigDecimal) query.uniqueResult()).longValue();`

Comment: This query is not valid HQL and my no longer work if Hibernate will become more strict. It should be select count(login) from LoginClass login

Answer (score 2):

The result returns BigDecimal and you need to convert it from Bigdecimal (java.math.BigDecimal) to Long so that no error, he solution would be this:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
        "select count(*) from login where login.emailid=:email and login.password=:password");
query.setString("email", "something");
query.setString("password", "password");
Long count = ((BigDecimal) query.uniqueResult()).longValue();
```

Comment: This query is not valid HQL and my no longer work if Hibernate will become more strict. It should be select count(login) from LoginClass login

Comment: no, it I did is with hibernate but native, it is already changed

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for the fix

Answer (score 0):

You can query in Hibernate 6 this way:

```
public int getCount() {
    int result = 0;
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();

        result = session.createNativeQuery("select count(*) from user", Integer.class).uniqueResult();

        session.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```