# Get count of results from hibernate select query (query returning an object not Select count(*))

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am having an HQL query

```
String q = "From TMainTable where a= ? and b= ? and c=?"
Query q = session.createQuery(q).setParameter(0,1).setParameter(1,2).setParameter(2,3);
int count = getCount(q);
List<TMainTable> list = q.setFirstResult(pageNo).setMaxResults(maxLimit).list()

public int getCount(Query q){
   return q.list().size();
}
```

But the getCount method is taking so much of time. Say my table has 10000 rows and I am getting only 20 records at a time with the actual count. What is the fastest method to get count using the Query object.

I have tried this in the getCount function

```
public Long getCount(Query q){
String queryString = q.getQueryString();
            String countQueryString = "Select count(*) From "+queryString.substring(0, q.getQueryString().indexOf(" From"));
            System.out.println(countQueryString);
            Long c= (Long)ctx.getSession().createQuery(countQueryString).uniqueResult();
return c;
}
```

But how can I set the parameters in the new query ? Is there a way I can alter only the query string in Query Object.

Comment: check this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383697/how-to-write-a-query-in-hibernate-for-count

Comment: its unclear: in the title there is "(query returning an object not Select count(*))" you mean you can't use a count query?

Comment: yeah , All I have in getCount function is the query object. I can get the query string and alter it to make a count query, but again I am not getting how to build the new query

Comment: so... if you can actually take the query and replace it... just make your own query and be done with it? 
It's like taking a hammer to cut something and try to sharpen it when you can just grab a pair of scissor

Comment: Yeah. I just edited the question and added what I was trying to do. In the Query object I need to edit the query string alone

Comment: my point still stand.in your example you take the old query, do some substring, create a new query and use that... is it that the actual query you take as input is variable?

Comment: Actually I am looking for scissors only, just that I am not finding that ;). So trying to adjust with hammer

Answer (score 1):

You have to set parameters starting with 1 not with 0 :

```
Query q = session.createQuery(q).setParameter(0,1).setParameter(1,2).setParameter(2,3);
//--------------------------------------------^-----------------^-----------------^
```

Instead you have to use :

```
Query q = session.createQuery(q).setParameter(1,1).setParameter(2,2).setParameter(3,3);
//--------------------------------------------^-----------------^-----------------^
```

---

Second to get size of your list, you can use `getResultList().size` like this :

```
public int getCount(Query q){
   return q.getResultList().size();
}
```

Comment: I am doing a q.list().size() which is very slow when my data is more

Answer (score 0):

You should see what kind of sql is generated by hibernate. It can be very inefficient. If so you should write native sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Conventionally, you would have two queries, one to do a count(*) formally, and a second for the actual query. The only way that the main query can get the number of results is by fully executing and then doing a count on the result list, which will be very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
  Query query = session.createQuery("select count(*) from Class_NAME as a where YOUR_CONDITION");
        try {
            return Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(query.uniqueResult()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Print stacktrace
            return 0;
        }
```